# WP REST API, Specific data retrieval should not require authentication, right?

Tags: json, wordpress

If i use the link mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ (or even category or tags in place of posts with a specific id of that category or tag (for an android application), i get the exact results. However, when i use something like this:

http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?tags=

It doesn't return me the specific data and only returns the json that has the data of http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts.

I know that authentication is needed for update and delete procedures but I am just trying to get the data and not edit it. Am I entering the correct route or will I have to use the authentication process to get the specific relevant data?

PS: When my website is logged on on wordpress, the query does return the exact data so i guess that is due to cookie authentication?

Comment: it's because your tags parameter is empty , you can try with some tag id

Comment: That was a formatting mistake i think. I have added the relevant id of tags. But even after adding the id, the problem persists. Anything?